# Dynamically replace html tags

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, replace

I'm trying to replace some html tags which are being generated by ajax script. Ajax script generates the following ul list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="odd">some text</li>
  <li class="even">some text</li>
  <li class="odd"><hr /></li>
  <li class="even">some text</li>
</ul>
```

I need to replace `<li class="odd"><hr /></li>` with `</ul><hr /><ul>`. I guess it has to be some javascript to dynamically replace those tags everytime the list is being generated, but I don't know how to do it exactly. Could you please point me to the right track?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. `hr` is **not** an allowed child element of `ul`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you change the script that generates the initial <ul>...</ul> to output the required markup to begin with?

Comment: Here is the story http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923355/yii-customize-the-results-of-cautocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should assign an id to your  such that it is easier to access :

```
<ul id='myTag'>
    [...]
</ul>
```

Then, you can use [string manipulation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) and the [innerHTML property](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php) to do what you want :

```
var html = document.getElementById('myTag').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('myTag').innerHTML = html.replace('<li class="odd"><hr /></li>', '</ul><hr /><ul>');
```

You could of course use fancy javascript libraries like jQuery or prototype to do the same, but this is the "roots" way ;) !

Answer (score 1):

Far out.  Well, (a), make it so you don't need to do that.  :)  Or (b):

1. Get a reference to that ul tag
   somehow.  give it an id attribute
   and use:
   `document.getElementById("theULTag")`.
   Or, if it's the first UL tag on the
   page for example, use
   `document.getElementsByTagName("ul").item(0)`
2. Now set a variable equal to this element's innerHtml attribute.  For example:  `var textToChange = document.getElementById("theULTag").innerHTML`
3. [learn about javascript string manipulation here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp), and do what you need to do.  (You might need to strip out spaces to make it easier on yourself)
4. Put your new text back in with `document.getElementById("theULTag").innerHTML = newText`

Good luck!

Comment: My answer was first!  Ah, I get no love . . .